# How to view a web request as it travels through apache rules

Tags: linux, apache, unix

I have written some apache rules, such as:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:8443%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
```

How can I debug to see what the request looks like at each stage of the apache process? For example:

- It starts off as X
- Apache applies rule1 and it becomes Y
- Apache applies rule2 and it becomes Z

How do I see exactly what's going on in this process?

Essentially, what I'm trying to figure out is why a websocket request is 404'ing. Here is what the request looks like:

```
Request URL: wss://mysite.com/ws/registration/1234/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: xh+D6ed0N9dL8p42ADD2lQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
```

What I'd like to see is:

1. Does Apache receive the request? (it obviously does)
2. Are any re-write rules applied?
3. What does the request 'finish' off as?
4. Finally, are there any 'print' rules you can give it, for example to see what the {REQUEST_URI} is?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to do this would be to set the highest level of debug (by default it's set to `error`) --

```
# /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
LogLevel trace8
```

This is the highest level and is probably too much information (such as the SSH connection info). But you can work your way down to the appropriate debug level [described here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel). Note that your server will become 'slow' while debugging things, so put it back to the appropriate level when done.

Additionally, you can grep through the output to find particular modules or parts you want to find (such as `mod_write`):

```
$ tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep --line-buffered mod_rewrite
```